# ApachePOI stops parsing excel file at missing cell regardless of missing cell policy

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am writing a script that parses over each row in an excel sheet and prints out the contents of each cell in that row. Here is the code:

```
    for(int cntr=1; cntr<=firstSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); cntr++){
        Row currentRow = firstSheet.getRow(cntr);
        System.out.println("-------------Working on Row Number: "+currentRow.getRowNum());
        for(int cntr2 = 0; cntr2<currentRow.getLastCellNum(); cntr2++){
            Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(cntr2, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
            if(currentCell==null){
                //cell doesn't have anything in there
                System.out.println("Cell in Row number "+(currentRow.getRowNum()+1)+" is null.");
            }
            switch(currentCell.getCellType()){
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println("Current Cell: "+currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.println("Current Cell: "+currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println("Current Cell: "+currentCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    System.out.println("Cell in row number "+(currentRow.getRowNum()+1)+" is returned as blank");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is that in the 11th row of my excel spreadsheet (10th row if you count starting at 0) there is a cell, 3 cells in to be exact, with nothing in it. Every time my script reaches this point, it throws a null pointer exception and stops running, though my IDE says the build was successful. I did some research into how to handle this, and found the MissingCellPolicy, which I used in the line

```
    Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(cntr2, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
```

but I still get a NullPointerException error. What is wrong with my algorithm?

Also, here is the output:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    ...

    -------------Working on Row Number: 10
    Current Cell: OC[C@H]1OC(O)[C@H](O)[C@@H](O)[C@@H]1O
    Current Cell: NCGC00159408-02
    Current Cell: DL-Glucose
    Current Cell: 180.16
    Current Cell: -3.51
    Current Cell: 6.0
    Current Cell: 5.0
    -------------Working on Row Number: 11
    Current Cell: OC[C@@H](O)C(O)[C@@H](O)CO
    Current Cell: NCGC00165982-01
    Cell in Row number 11 is null.
   at excellibrarycreation.ExcelFileProcesser.processFile(ExcelFileProcesser.java:64)
   at excellibrarycreation.ExcelLibraryCreation.main(ExcelLibraryCreation.java:25)
```

Java Result: 1
        BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)

Comment: This doesn't really affect the problem but in case anyone is confused why my first counter (int cntr) starts at 1, I am skipping the first row because it just acts as a header in my excel spreadsheet. Thanks

Comment: better catch that Nullpointer Exception so that your program would not terminate abnormally

Comment: Even if I catch it, the script will still stop. Besides, ideally I want to add the information from each row into an array, so I would like it if empty cells could be written as "empty" or null.

Comment: can you just let us know what is written on line 64 of ExcelFileProcesser

Comment: Line 64 is: switch(currentCell.getCellType()){

Comment: You should also check if the row is null - null rows are a valid response to `getRow(num)` if the row has never had any data stored in it

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for the tip. I'll be sure to check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this in your code

```
    if(currentCell==null){
                //cell doesn't have anything in there
      System.out.println("Cell in Row number "+(currentRow.getRowNum()+1)+" is null.");
      continue;// continue if row is null..meaning do not go to switch case statement
                    }

            }
            switch(currentCell.getCellType()){
         ////you do not want to enter here if currentCell is null
                //cell doesn't have anything in there}
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Ha, I didn't know the continue statement existed in Java. I thought that was only in Groovy. But anyway it reads all the way until the end  very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please perform Two changes and see, I think it should work:

1st remove '=' from for loop

```
for(int cntr=1; cntr<firstSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); cntr++){
```

2nd use, if it is not altering your result/requirement

```
Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies with that if statement.

```
Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(cntr2, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
if(currentCell==null){
    ...
}
switch(currentCell.getCellType()){
               .
               .
               .
}
```

Regardless of whether `currentCell` is null or not, you put it into the switch statement. This will cause the swtich statement to throw a `NullPointerException` when `currentCell.getCellType()` is called if  `currentCell` is `null`. To get rid of this put the switch statement into an `else` clause like so:

```
Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(cntr2, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
if(currentCell==null){
    ...
} else {
    switch(currentCell.getCellType()){
                   .
                   .
                   .
    }
}
```